# Building Spring 3.0.1 - Failing Tests

Tags: spring, ant, junit, build

I'm trying to build a patched version of Spring 3.0.1 but i'm facing test case failures. On analyzing further, i saw that the failing tests are the ones that have been marked as @Ignore, but still they seem to be executed.

What could be the problem?

Here's the steps that i've followed to build spring 3.0.1

```
git clone git://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework.git
git checkout v3.0.1.RELEASE
```

Checked out https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-build/trunk/project-build to a folder under the spring-framework folder using svn.  Switched to the build-spring-framework directory.  Created some directories with mkdir from the steps mentioned [here](http://kensipe.blogspot.in/2009/04/building-spring-3-with-git.html).

```
set JAVA_HOME=E:\Syndev\JAVA6U24\JDK
set ANT_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1024m
ant
```

Another thing I tried was to simply remove the failing tests/delete the test case files, but that led to the following exception further down the build.

```
 [junit] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
 [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:359)
 [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 [junit]     at org.springframework.core.OverridingClassLoader.loadClass(OverridingClassLoader.java:70)
 [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 [junit]     at org.springframework.context.support.ContextTypeMatchClassLoader.loadClass(ContextTypeMatchClassLoader.java:63)
 [junit]     at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
 [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1226)
 [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1200)
 [junit]
 [junit]
 [subant] Leaving directory: E:\Projects\github\spring-framework\org.springframework.orm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be documented here,

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8089

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8587

So the above exception from HibernateEntityManagerFactoryIntegrationTests.java and other exceptions in classes such as NotificationListenerTests.java, Log4jWebConfigurerTests.java should be fixed by simply deleting the tests from there.